# Error: /index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: spring, jsf

My project structure is shown below.

[image]

Here library

[image]

When i browser `http://localhost:8080/springMOTHER-jsf/index.xhtml` then it don't display page `index.xhtml`

[image]

I'm begining with JSF, Please let me know Why ???

Here file `web.xml`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
          version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>    
</web-app>
```

Comment: Project structure looks weird and you're all dependent on `pom.xml` whether WAR file will be build correctly. This is not a JSF problem, just Eclipse+Maven.

Comment: @BalusC, your opinion , having wrong with file `pom.xml`. I have posted file `pom.xml`, you can check help me !